# ImageMagick: Converting RGB PNG to CMYK TIFF generate solarized output

Tags: python, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, image-conversion

I've solid black PNG (rgb 0,0,0), which I want to convert to CMYK TIFF. But it is not full black in output. I've set ICC color profiles correctly and also have set colorspace correctly. If I will do the same in PS or FastStone image viewer, I get same color as input PNG. Following is the command I use:

```
magick.exe "P:\Python\mask.png" -profile "P:\Python\sRGB.icc" -profile "P:\Python\USWebCoatedSWOP.icc" -colorspace CMYK "P:\Python\mask.tiff"
```

Please help me, this is really important for me.

Best regards,
Ishaq

Comment: Try changing the colourspace to CMYK **before** adding the profile.

Comment: It produces same output.

Comment: Did you check the output of both commands with `magick identify -verbose mask.tiff` to see if both contain the ICC profile?

Comment: I can verify it in PS. I open both tiff's and have same colors, which are not black. I try different ICC profiles as well with no luck.

Comment: Can you try to figure it out on your side? What causes the color to get reddish? I shall be very thankful to be helped. Can even pay.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use both profiles and -colorspace. If your input image has a color profile, then use only one profile. If it has no profiles, then use two profiles.

The following works fine for me on ImageMagick 7.0.11.3 Q16 Mac OSX. Perhaps the issue is with your viewer.

If this does  not work for you, zip your input file and post it. Also identify your exact ImageMagick version and platform.

Create binary mask image:

```
magick logo: -transparent white -alpha extract mask.png
```

[image]

Process mask image:

```
magick mask.png -profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/sRGB.icc /Users/fred/images/profiles/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc -type colorseparation mask.tif
```

[image]

Comment: If don't specify colorspace, I get a warning in Photoshop. The reason you get correct color is because output is still in RGB, not in CMYK.

Comment: Add -type colorseparation just before the output in my command above. I have edited my answer as such. Do not add -colorspace CMYK.

Comment: I do not know why it does not end up with black as cmyk(0,0,0,255)

Comment: Yes brother same results. I had in-depth analysis, where I find algorithm IM uses for CMYK conversion is not so advanced (hence not accurate); where full black is set by K=100%; while PS converts full black by C=75,M=68,Y=67,K=90. I also found an article for such discussion:
https://www.bittbox.com/culture/photoshop-101-true-black-cmyk

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done by using PIL

from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('your_image.png')

img.save('image.tiff')

Comment: We've to define color profile and colorspace as defined in ImageMagick command. Even I do that, still color is no longer full black.

Comment: Ok got it. I hope you find the solution.